# Unset Designer from variable

Tags: php, unset

I am displaying product Id, product name , designer, but i need to hide "designer".

[image]

so i am trying to unset `designer` from variable $orderitems, i am trying below code, but still Designer column displaying

i am fetching product id , name , Designer from this code : `->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')` & trying this code to unset : `unset($orderitems['designer_id'])`

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {
    $user_home = new USER();
    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']
    ));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));
        }
      else
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ))

->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id') 
->addAttributeToSelect('state');    
//unset($orderitems['designer_id']);
        }

    $i = 0;
    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {
            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(
                    ":designerorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
                ));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $productdetail->getName() ,
                    $designerName,
                    $orderData['status'],
                    $orderData['grand_total'],
                    $orderData['customer_email'],
                    $commission,
                    $dorderStatus,
                    $sDate
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    unset($orderitems['designer_id']);
    }
```

Note : I really tried lot before posting here, i am new to php.

Comment: You are selecting * with the wildcard, why shouldnt u just query the specific columns you need? You are also displaying the designer id in the json array

Comment: @ImAtWar there are 2 things , for `admin login` = > i need to `display all`, for `designer login` = > i need to `hide designer column`

Comment: So add an if statement to verify if the user is admin

Comment: @ImAtWar sorry, i am new to php , i did't got , can you please tell what code i need to use ?

Comment: You need to get familiar with if statements. They are widely used in multiple programming languages.

Comment: sure @ImAtWar , i will learn it, can you please help for this issue ?